# NumbeFormatException Issue

Tags: java

I'm trying to use a simple cmd line calculator to print out "Wrong Input: " plus the number with variable i.e."4x" when it's found within args[]. I've tried implementing RegEx to no avial and now I'm trying to use the Patter and Matcher libraries to figure it out. I thought that maybe using "stringMatch.find(element)" would work but "element" isn't able to be placed in the method find(). Any help is appreciated..

```
public class Calculator {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //check number of strings passed
    if (args.length != 3) {
        System.out.println("usage: java Calculator operand1 operator operand2");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    //result of the operation
    int result =0;
    Pattern stringPat = Pattern.compile("\\d");
    Matcher stringMatch = stringPat.matcher("");


    //determine the operator
    try{

        switch (args[1].charAt(0)) {
            case '+':
                result = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) + Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
                break;
            case '-':
                result = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) - Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
                break;
            case '*':
                result = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) * Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
                break;
            case '/':
                result = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) / Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
                break;
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        for(String element: args)
            if (stringMatch.find()){
                System.out.println("Wrong Input: " + element);
                System.exit(0);
            }
    }
    //display result
    System.out.println(args[0] + ' ' + args[1] + ' ' + args[2] + " = " + result);
}
}
```

Comment: You can change your condition from `if (stringMatch.find())` to `if (!element.contains("\\d"))` It'll print the first nonnumerical value.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's part of it but if you put in something like, "4 + 2x" It will still output "4" instead of "2x" like it should. So, I guess part of the problem is solved..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the logic clean and simple, it's probably better to do the valid value check before you reach the switch and if that passes then continue. Have a look at my sample solution below and try trace the logic through.  You can use a `try...catch` block to catch the parse error which will mean an invalid integer was passed in.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length != 3) {
      System.out.println("usage: java Calculator operand1 operator operand2");
      return;
    }
    Integer firstValue;
    Integer secondValue;
    try {
      firstValue = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      System.out.println("Invalid value:" + args[0]);
      return;
    }
    try {
      secondValue = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      System.out.println("Invalid value:" + args[2]);
      return;
    }
    char operator = args[1].charAt(0);
    int result;
    switch (operator) {
      case '+':
        result = Math.addExact(firstValue, secondValue);
        break;
      case '-':
        result = Math.subtractExact(firstValue, secondValue);
        break;
      case '*':
        result = Math.multiplyExact(firstValue, secondValue);
        break;
      case '/':
        result = Math.floorDiv(firstValue, secondValue);
        break;
      default:
        System.out.println("Invalid operator");
        return;
    }
    System.out.println(args[0] + ' ' + args[1] + ' ' + args[2] + " = " + result);
  }
```

If you have any questions or need clarification on anything I've done feel free to reply to this post and I'll try help you out :)

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been dealing with this headache since like 9am est. I do have a question though, for the args variables you created "Integer firstValue" and "Integer secondValue" why did you use the full word instead of the abbreviated "int?"

Comment: Integer is a wrapper class - its an object & int is a primitive.  Integer can hold numbers and can also hold a null value (Objects can be null).  Integer also comes with some built in wrapper class methods such as `firstValue.toString()` which will turn your value to a string for example... A primitive cannot hold null, and does not have `.toString()` nor does it have the other methods available to a wrapper.  primitives are not objects. Primitives are just values. Java has autoboxing which turns primitives into objects during compile time anyway.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for that explanation also. You're awesome :)